# Quotations spanning multiple paragraphs in csquotes with french guillemets under LyX

Tags: lyx, typography, csquotes

This question was already raised and answered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53460/quotations-spanning-multiple-paragraphs-in-csquotes) for american:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\DeclareQuoteStyle[american]{english}% verified
  {\textquotedblleft}
  [\textquotedblleft]
  {\textquotedblright}
  [0.05em]
  {\textquoteleft}
  {\textquoteright}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\begin{document}

"This is a quotation," he said.  "It continues onto the next paragraph.

Here is the continuation of my quote.  As per literary convention,
there is no end-quote at the end of the previous paragraph."

\end{document}
```

But I need to adapt it for french.

Normally, in a LyX document, putting the first part before `\begin{document}` in the preambule, and the rest except `\begin` and `\end` in the LyX editor should work (except document class is declared in the LyX interface, and LyX declares `\language`).

**First problem:** in the pdf produced, I don't have the middle quote (the one which begins the intermediate paragraphs.

**Second problem:** I have tried to adapt the code for french, but without success:

```
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[frenchle]{babel}
%\usepackage[american]{babel}
\DeclareQuoteStyle[french]{guillemets}
%\DeclareQuoteStyle[american]{english}% verified
  {\guillemotleft}
  [\guillemotleft]
  {\guillemotright}
  [0.05em]
  {\guillemotleft}
  {\guillemotright}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
```

The pdf output is exactly the same. But I assume it is linked to point 1. So, here is the full LyX code (`\language` shall be edited by hand in a text editor, otherwise, LyX proposes français in its interface, but then it issues an error):

```
#LyX 2.1 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 474
\begin_document
\begin_header
\textclass article
\begin_preamble
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[frenchle]{babel}
%\usepackage[american]{babel}
\DeclareQuoteStyle[french]{guillemets}
%\DeclareQuoteStyle[american]{english}% verified
  {\guillemotleft}
  [\guillemotleft]
  {\guillemotright}
  [0.05em]
  {\guillemotleft}
  {\guillemotright}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
%\MakeAutoQuote{«}{»}
\end_preamble
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language frenchle
\language_package default
\inputencoding utf8
\fontencoding global
\font_roman default
\font_sans default
\font_typewriter default
\font_math auto
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100
\font_tt_scale 100
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Verbatim

\end_layout

\begin_layout Verbatim
"This is a quotation," he said.
  "It continues onto the next paragraph.
\end_layout

\begin_layout Verbatim

\end_layout

\begin_layout Verbatim
Here is the continuation of my quote.
  As per literary convention,
\end_layout

\begin_layout Verbatim
there is no end-quote at the end of the previous paragraph."
\end_layout

\begin_layout Verbatim

\end_layout

\begin_layout Verbatim
blabla
\end_layout

\begin_layout Verbatim

\end_layout

\begin_layout Verbatim
«This is a quotation,» he said.
  «It continues onto the next paragraph.
\end_layout

\begin_layout Verbatim

\end_layout

\begin_layout Verbatim
Here is the continuation of my quote.
  As per literary convention,
\end_layout

\begin_layout Verbatim
there is no end-quote at the end of the previous paragraph.»
\end_layout

\begin_layout Verbatim

\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

**Third point:** I wonder if I could use `\MakeAutoQuote{«}{»}` with `\DeclareQuoteStyle` to be able to type `«some text»` in the LyX editor instead of `"some text"`. I want to use `«some text»` instead of `« some text »`, but of course still output `« some text »` when french style is selected in the preambul.

Answer (score 1):

With the below code, I managed to get this with plain `pdflatex`:

[image: test.png]

... not sure if that's what you wanted. It seems you had to (re-)do `\DeclareQuoteAlias[french]{guillemets}{french}` for problems 1 and 2; and `\MakeAutoQuote{«}{»}` specifically in preamble for problem 3. Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagecolor{yellow!10}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % must have, to be able to enter {«}{»} for \MakeAutoQuote
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\DeclareQuoteStyle[french]{guillemets}
%\DeclareQuoteStyle[american]{english}% verified
  {\guillemotleft}
  [\guillemotleft]
  {\guillemotright}
  [0.05em]
  {\guillemotleft}
  {\guillemotright}
\MakeAutoQuote{«}{»} % works fine here (with utf8 support)
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
% from tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.def:
% http://de.comp.text.tex.narkive.com/bQLQv3EF/csquotes-und-blockquote
\DeclareQuoteAlias[french]{guillemets}{french}

\begin{document}
\typeout{language is \languagename} % language is french

"This is a quotation," he said.  "It continues onto the next paragraph.

Here is the continuation of my quote.  As per literary convention,
there is no end-quote at the end of the previous paragraph."

% \MakeAutoQuote{«}{»} % passes here, if not used in preamble - but doesn't add the « on the second paragraph
% \MakeOuterQuote{«} % causes "! Package csquotes Error: Invalid argument."

«This is a quotation,» he said.  «It continues onto the next paragraph.

Here is the continuation of my quote.  As per literary convention,
there is no end-quote at the end of the previous paragraph.»

\end{document}
```